# How to get the last page of any Firestore query?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

How do I get the last page of any Firestore query without needing to send the cursor value for the last document in the query?

Obviously the first/last value is not always known unless I manually keep track of those values. I have queries that order by many different fields so having to store first/last cursor values for each of those seems like a lot of unnecessary work.

Getting the entire query result without limit is obviously expensive and impractical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There currently isn't a way to get the last list. The common way to do this is to:

1. Reverse the order of the query.
2. Request the first page of results.
3. Reverse the results client-side again to get them in the right order.

---

Note though that there is talk (and even work being done) to add a `limitToLast()` operation to Firestore's query mechanism, which would allow you to get precisely the result you're looking for. It just isn't available yet. The biggest differences would be that you can skip steps 1 and 3 from the workaround.